# Why is my file system mounted as read-only?

Tags: linux, filesystems, readonly

I've put together a small system with busybox, a Linux kernel, and a small file system, putting stuff in as it seemed necessary -- I don't know if I've been learning much from this, but I started out pretty clueless, so it sure hasn't been a smooth ride. So I suspect I might be missing some stuff in my filesystem, but I'm really not sure what I might need to add next.

I can boot into my system by typing in the following grub commands:
[image: set root=(hd0,msdos1) \ linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 \ boot]

Once the boot messages stop, I'm left with this (I'm not sure if it's related but there's a line there that says: `VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) readonly on device 8:1`):
[image: boot message]

I can't modify the filesystem:
[image: ln: bin/mkdir Read-only file]

It's funny because I can manually mount /proc just fine:
[image: mounting /proc]

Why is my file system read-only? What would I need to set up to get it to work?

Comment: It's not unusual for a system to boot `/` readonly at first and then remount it rw later on. (I think the idea is that one would like to get to binaries like the file system check e2fsck in `/sbin/` without risking breaking anything.)

Comment: maybe your filesystem is corrupt, have you tried to check it ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to search in `dmesg | less`.

If you would like remount it to read-write, use `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: I run that command but got `mount: cannot remount /dev/mmcblk0p2 read-write, is write-protected`.

Comment: mmcblk0p2 sounds like an SD card. These (or micro-SD to SD adapters) often have a small physical switch on the side that sets them read-only.

Comment: @SAMPro how did you fix this?  (same question for any reader who fixed it; please help the community!  I'm getting the same message

Comment: Any found the solution for write-protected

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar issue that is not solved with the solution above. Linux may mount a drive as *'read-only'* because of Fastboot on Windows 10. A shutdown with the Fastboot feature keeps the Windows kernel and session running albeit it closes all applications and logs off users. By turning off Fastboot, windows will do a cold shutdown and linux will be able to mount the drive safely. You will loose the fast windows boot as a consequence.

To turn-off fast-boot on windows 10 do the following:

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Click Power Options.
3. Choose "what the power buttons do."
4. Click "Change settings that are currently unavailable."
5. Find and uncheck "Turn on fast startup."
6. Save changes.
7. Shutdown and boot linux.

References:
https://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/
https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/

Comment: I doubt, this is a reasonable answer for a question from 2012. But as a reader from the future, I very much appreciate the pointer into the right direction.

Comment: it worked like charm.

Comment: Thanks a lot, working indeed like a charm

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solution worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time.

Comment: The problem I had was that -also on a dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows- Windows didn't cleanly unmount its drives (hard reset).
Just booting into Windows, cleanly shutting down and restarting in Ubuntu solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

@Diaz Great advice, solved my issue. However, the "Turn on fast startup" didn't turn up in my Windows 10 installation. So I disabled the feature directly in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\Power\HiberbootEnabled=0
```

Booted Debian and voila - SDD rw again.